# What is the meaning of `1:` in the version of a yum package?

Tags: linux, yum, version

I have an Amazon linux machine. When I run `yum list installed` to list all the versions of the packages I've installed, I see one line saying

```
pkgconfig.x86_64                       1:0.27.1-2.7.amzn1                 installed
```

Why does the version starts with `1:`? What does it mean? I haven't seen any version like this before.

If I run `sudo yum install pkgconfig-1:0.27.1-2.7.amzn1`, I got an error saying `No package pkgconfig-1:0.27.1-2.7.amzn1 available.`.

However, I can run `sudo yum install pkgconfig-0.27.1-2.7.amzn1` to correctly install `pkgconfig` whose version is `0.27.1-2.7.amzn1`.

What does `1:` mean in the version?

Answer (score 2):

this is the [epoch](https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io/#epoch) number.

It somehow overrides the version numbers: `3.0.0` < `1:1.0.0` < `2:0.1.0` etc. This would allow developers to change their numbering scheme but keep the updates going. `yum` mostly prints the `epoch`, but doesn't accept it as input on most of his commands. It can be a little bit disturbing, yes :)

Comment: Current versions of `yum` [claim to support epochs in package specifications](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/yum.8.html#SPECIFYING_PACKAGE_NAMES), but that might be a recent change...